# Uncaught RangeError: Invalid string length when appending to a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

So basically I've been working on a small personal project of mine in Javascript, and I've hit a snag. I'm trying to generate a list in HTML from a 2D array using Javascript. Here is my code:

```
function generatePageFromArray(page, array){
var entry, i, j;
for (i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    entry = array[i];
    for (j = 0; j < entry.length; j = j + 2) {
        page = page + '<tr>'+
                    '<td class="favoritesContainer"><input type="checkbox" class="favorites"></input></td>';
        page = page +  '<td class="english">' + entry[j,0] + '</td>';
        page = page +  '<td class="spanish">';
        if (entry[j,1].indexOf("|") > 0){
            var spanishTerms = entry[j,1].split("|");
            var strLength = spanishTerms.size;
            for (i = 0; i < strLength; i++){
                page = page.concat(spanishTerms[i] + '<br>');   
            }
        }
        else{
            page = page + entry[j,1];
        }
        page = page + '</td>'
        page = page + '</tr>';         
    }
}
return page;}
```

It keeps throwing a Uncaught RangeError: Invalid string length on this line:

```
page = page + '<tr>'+
                    '<td class="favoritesContainer"><input type="checkbox" class="favorites"></input></td>';
```

I have no idea why. I've also tried using .concat() to append, but nothing.

Comment: This: `entry[j,0]` means exactly the same thing as `entry[0]` - what do you intend for that to do?

Comment: It is actually a 2D array iteration...

Comment: Accessing a 2-dimensional array in JavaScript looks like `entry[j][0]`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your 2-D array accesses are incorrect, but the main problem is that you're re-using the variable `i` in an inner loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < strLength; i++){
    page = page.concat(spanishTerms[i] + '<br>');   
}
```

That `i` will be the same `i` as in your outer loop. Thus, the error you're getting is telling you that you're building up a massive string that exceeds the capacity of the runtime system. Declare a new variable for that loop.

Accessing a value from an array of arrays requires two sets of `[ ]`:

```js
entry[j][0]
```

Comment: @axtscz no, they're not, if you're talking about JavaScript. If you're talking about something else, you should not have tagged the question with the JavaScript tag.

Comment: Check out the difference: http://jsfiddle.net/byg8p8q5/ Your suggestion launches first.

Comment: @axtscz I assure you with 100% confidence that the 2-D syntax you're trying to use will not do what you think it will. The `,` in the `[ ]` index is parsed as the JavaScript comma operator, which means that the value of the index will be the value of the second expression. That's why `j, 1` is exactly the same as just `1` and `j, 0` is exactly the same as just `0`.

Comment: Did you look at the jsfiddle? I can't explain it either

Comment: @axtscz now that I see your code, it's clear that you don't need that inner loop (the one with `j`) at all.

Comment: @axtscz [here is a fixed version of your jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wmqtyor4/)

Answer (score 0):

I got this error:

Uncaught RangeError: Invalid string length

And Fix it by use i for outer for loop, use DIFFERENT j for inner for loop.

I have outer for loop use i, and inner for loop still with i, 
then the error above, took me many hours to figure out the real problem is conflict of 2 i,

```
for (var i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
   for (var i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
      i;// conflict i will cause error above
   }
}
```

You must use j or different letters for inner loop